# Which filter affects the 'entry-title' post class

Tags: plugins, filters, css, title

I created a plugin setting a $var to true if the post belongs to category 'a', and set the same $var to false if the post belongs to category 'b', it works and I can get the correct value depends on the category

what I need is to find a filter helps me to add an extra text to the `entry-title` post class  so I can change post title align or color if if the post category is `a` without editing content.php file.

Here is the code:

```
function change_my_entry-title(){
    if ($var === true){
        return 'entry-title_cat_a';
    }else{
        return 'entry-title';
    }
}
add_filter(' ..... ','change_my_entry-title');
```

So which `filter_name` I should put instead of `.....`

Comment: There is no `entry-title` class added by WordPress core, it is likely part of theme markup.

Comment: To confirm @Rarst's observation, I `grep`ed my dev install and the only place that `entry-title` appears is in Twenty Thirteen's markup. It is theme markup and it is hard coded. There is no filter. Perhaps your theme uses the same class name and there is a filter, but that is impossible to say without more information.

Comment: I hope they can add a filter to let site owner control that part of CSS without edit the core code of Wordpress

Comment: This code pertains to a theme, not the core wordpress. It's completely okay to modify the theme to suits your needs. Your changes won't be erased with the next wordpress update.

Answer (score 0):

The filter that allows you to tweak the title value is `[wp_title][1]`. As mentioned by the commenters, the entry-title is a class pertaining to your theme.

If you need to set a class according to a certain value, try something like this
in your template file:

```
<h1 class="<?php echo ($in_category_a) ? 'align-left': ''; ?>"><?php the_title();?></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you. It means that no way other than editing the content.php file

Comment: yes. Note that if this is for a specific custom post type, you can duplicate content.php and name the new file content-{custom_post_type_name}.php so that change only affects the relevant items. See the Wordpress Template Hierarchy to understand how Wordpress picks which theme file to use for rendering your content: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: Yes I got, but my main point is using it in a plugin can be reusable for any wordpress user even if he don't know much about coding or template customizing